# I am confused with dot to dot vector multiplication

Tags: algebra-precalculus

I am confused with how to do the dot product of two vectors in the image shown. Can someone walk me through this? Is the dot product the vector in between the two vectors?

[image]

Comment: The dot product of two vectors results in a scalar, not a vector.

Comment: I would look up scalar projection as a prerequisite.  That made the whole thing crystal clear for me.

Comment: What is said in your book ?

Comment: As a complement to the other answers, here's a rough intuition for your image. If all the vectors have length approximately $1$, then, for example, ${\bf a \cdot b} \approx 0$ and ${\bf a \cdot d} \approx -1$ since $\bf a$ is more or less perpendicular to $\bf b$ and pointing away from $\bf d$. On the other hand, since $\bf b$ and $\bf c$ point in the same direction, then ${\bf b \cdot c} \approx 1$.

Comment: @Théophile Sorry, I missed that!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The dot product measures, roughly speaking, how much two vectors align to the same direction. If you know the lengths of two vectors and the angle $\theta$ between them, then
$$v\cdot w = \|v\|\|w\|\cos\theta.$$

You can also write the dot product in terms of the vector between $v$ and $w$ if you want:

$$\|v-w\|^2 = \|v\|^2 + \|w\|^2 - 2v\cdot w$$

which you can solve for the dot product.

Comment: wait so for the dot product of a and b, it would be negative?

Comment: @ilikepi314 Yep! It’s negative if the vectors point in opposite directions.

Comment: I understand now. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

The dot product is a scalar, not a vector. If you want the geometric definition then the dot product is the product of the lengths of the two vectors times the cosine of the angle between them.